# Unable to copy the file to docker host

Tags: docker, containers, docker-machine, mounted-volumes

I am trying to execute the below docker command where I am trying to get the 'Orthanc.json" file to my system folder which is "orthanc".

```
docker run --rm --entrypoint=cat jodogne/orthanc /etc/orthanc/orthanc.json >  
 orthanc/orthanc.json
```

under **/etc/orthanc/orthanc.json** - It is a directory and not a file - Am not able to use vim editor to read/open the file. - This is a public one. Anyone can access using this link [Orthanc link](https://book.orthanc-server.com/users/docker.html)

I get the below error message, Can you please help me understand what is the issue?

```
-bash: /orthanc/orthanc.json: Is a directory
```

orthanc.json should be a file but why does it treat it as a directory?

when I use vim orthanc.json, it throws an error message that it's a directory.

What should I be doing to see this as a config file as I have to make changes to it?

Comment: You can use -v(volume mount) to map your docker file system to your host so that you can access the file directly from your host

Comment: Even if I do that, it would still be a directory. Am I right? I expect it to be json config file.But any idea why it isn't file but a directory?

Comment: Json config file where I can make changes to the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've somehow already got a directory named `/orthanc/orthanc.json` on your host system. Remove it and try again.

```sh
rmdir /orthanc/orthanc.json     # if empty
rm -rf /orthanc/orthanc.json    # if not empty -- but see what's in there first!
```

Comment: Yes. "Orthanc.json" - is empty in host system. I am able to get into it using "cd orthanc.json" and it's empty. So you mean to say that my host system shouldn't have "orthanc" and "orthanc.json" folder. So the above docker run command will automatically create that folder? Can you please let me know how the command should look like?

Comment: But even in /etc/orthanc/orthanc.json - orthanc.json not a file? Did you get to check that link which I have shared?

Comment: The host system should have `/orthanc`, but it shouldn't have a directory `/orthanc/orthanc.json`. `/orthan/orthanc.json` should either not exist or it should be a file.

Comment: I saw that even under cd /etc/orthanc/prthanc.json - orthanc.json is a empty directory. I guess it is corrupted. Can I just delete/remove the /etc/ directory as a whole? Will it affect anything?